# VT100 Save/Restore background content

Tags: screen, putty, vt100, teraterm

I am drawing a text-based window from an embedded system (a PIC32 micro).
I am using VT100 commands and a serial port terminal software (TeraTerm) to do it.

I would like to save the background before paint the window, and then restore the background after use it.

1. Save background area.
2. Paint a text-based window.
3. After use the windows, restore the background content.

I Googled around and found the command DECCRA for copy rectangle areas, but it is not well supported by TeraTerm/Putty/Others.

Is there an alternative way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VT100 features are a *subset* of VT220 are a subset of VT420. **`VT100`**'s don't do **`DECCRA`**: that is a **`VT420`** feature.

If you did have **`DECCRA`** support, it would not solve the problem you are interested in, because

- the escape sequences would only affect the visible part of the screen.
- colors would not be copied, anyway.

Some terminal emulators (thinking of xterm) have a *print-screen* feature which could be configured to write to a file.  In the case of xterm, the "print" can be configured to write color- and video-attribute information, so in principle one could read back this information and print it to the screen.  Offhand, PuTTY does not do that (its print-screen feature doesn't save the color/video information).